# magento 1.9 different shipping price for each state / province

Tags: magento-1.9, price, shipping

I have magento 1.9.3.8 and i want to set a different shipping price for each state/province i tried to configure it from dashboard but i couldn't ,  any solution for this ?

Comment: You can use webshopapps matrix rate extension.

Comment: Can't i do it from database?

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: Happy to help. Upvote please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tablerate shipping method which is already available on Magento by default. You can manage the shipping rate by country, state, zipcodes etc by csv. You can get a better idea from here: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/shipping/table-rates.html

If you want advanced version of tablerate then you need to free extension webshopapps matrixrate. You can download it from here: https://webshopapps.com/uk/magento-1-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

Hope this helps!